# Which package for console toggle bug?

Tags: 14.10, startup, launchpad, bug-reporting, console

I want to file a bug report on Launchpad about a problem with me not being able to switch to console view from the GUI loading screen on start up. When I try to toggle, the console view has been replaced by a black screen, although it is normally fine on shut down. And this only started to occur when I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10.

But I have got a slight problem at the moment, I don't know which package to report it under... So I was hoping that someone here could help with that.

As stated before, I am currently running Ubuntu 14.10. The output for the command `lspci` is:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
```

And using the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> I am able to switch to the console view successfully while I am logged in, and also able to switch back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. So which package should I report it under?

The output of `cat /etc/init/tty1.conf` is:

```
# tty1 - getty
#
# This service maintains a getty on tty1 from the point the system is
# started until it is shut down again.

start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345] and (
            not-container or
            container CONTAINER=lxc or
            container CONTAINER=lxc-libvirt)

stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

Please let me know if you require any more information to answer my question about which package on Launchpad I should report this under and I will edit my question to include that information.

Comment: Seems to me you can toggle fine, but the console program (`getty` or `agetty`) hasn't started. Does this happen for all the TTYs? Does the console show up later on?

Comment: During startup, not at all. I can as stated get to the console while logged in. And there is no problem with toggling to the console when shutting down.

Comment: "to switch to console view from the GUI loading screen on start up." I would assume this is due to the video card driver. Try switching the driver from add.drivers.

Comment: Could you give the output of `cat /etc/init/tty1.conf`?

Comment: @Fabby: Ok, I have edited my post to include that information.

Comment: It's started at the correct run level.  Could you install bootchart and share a boot chart with us???

Comment: @Fabby: I am just installing that now...

Comment: @Fabby: Sorry, but I am unable to provide the png which it is meant to generate as I seem to be experiencing this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bootchart/+bug/580560

Comment: @Fabby: Although I could provide the .tgz file which it provides, would that still be fine if I provide that instead? :)

Comment: @Fabby: You can get the `.tgz` file here if it is of any use: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ht52jgwqncukag/nikita-Lenovo-B590-utopic-20150120-1.tgz?dl=0

Comment: Tried generating the png on my system and it seems the input files are malformed...  It's a bug in the collection, not the generation...  :(

Comment: @Fabby: Oh dear... :( Are there any other tools that I could use, or anything that I could do?

Comment: I still think you need to re-install.  Your machine is even becoming too weird for me!  And Fabby=Weird² !!!  ;-)